# Como lidar com usuário que responde com grosseria?

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade, comentários, sinalização

Salvei um screenshot caso o comentário seja apagado:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100670/vps-linux-configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o?noredirect=1#comment205234_100670

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Independente do usuário conhecer ou não as normas, a reação dele não justifica; pois não foi uma resposta educada.

Comment: Bem, quando o autor de uma pergunta me ataca com esse tipo de coisa, normalmente eu apenas clico no botão do downvote e lavo as minhas mãos. Mas pensando bem, acho que ele pensou que você o estava atacando e daí se colocou no contra-ataque.

Comment: Talvez o melhor seria dar uma flag e deixar que os moderadores acalmem os ânimos que se exaltarem, coisa que eles normalmente conseguem fazer com maestria (só em um ou outro caso que as coisas dão errado).

Comment: pois é ... se ele tivesse postado apenas "não entendi".. estaria ok.. mas adicionou uma frase grosseira, desnecessariamente.. DEixa o cara.. nem precisa negativar.. ele já se queima sozinho mesmo..

Comment: Pior que o OP não é tão novo assim no SOpt, provavelmente ele te entendeu mal, apesar de sua resposta não ter nada demais. De qualquer forma, não justifica responder daquela forma.

Comment: Relacionada: [Página - Debate civil respeitoso em falta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4072/página-debate-civil-respeitoso-em-falta)

Comment: Poxa que coisa chata, passei 2 vezes por isso, na primeira era uma pergunta minha, um usuário respondeu, eu expliquei que a resposta dele nada tinha haver com a pergunta e ele atirou algumas ofensas tentei dialogar e tentei ser gentil, pedindo desculpas se pareci ríspido e pedi que edita-se a respostas, ele me atacou com mais grosserias, tentei dialogar mais uma vez, mas ele só atacava cheio de "mimimi sou uma vitima". O outro eu comentei pedindo detalhes do problema me atacou com grosserias, conversei e expliquei a comunidade pra ele, me pediu desculpas e foi amigável na conversa a seguir...

Answer (score 25):

> Sinalize hoje, sinalize amanhã, sinalize sempre.

Comentários ofensivos e rudes devem ser removidos e nós moderadores estamos sempre atentos a isso.

Além disso, dependendo do grau da ofensa o usuário pode ser advertido ou suspenso, sempre com o objetivo de que o site seja um lugar agradável e divertido para todos.

### Nunca responda com outra grosseria

Se lhe falta paciência, sinalize e siga em frente, vá para outra pergunta.

Se tiver nervos de aço e acha que pode ajudar, sinalize, mas ignore a grosseria e responda em bom tom para continuar uma conversa construtiva.

Comment: Eu perguntei aqui porque pensei que seria exagero sinalizar para um moderador. Obrigado por esclarecer.

Comment: @DanielOmine Raramente é exagero sinalizar para os moderadores... Se eles não tiverem nenhuma sinalização pra tratar, eles ficam entediados `;)`

Answer (score 13):

*Isto não é uma resposta*, é apenas algo do meu pensamento para refletir (claro que pode discordar de mim, afinal de contas os pensamentos das pessoas de um ano atrás não são os mesmos de hoje assim como daqui um ano poderemos ter ideias totalmente diferentes).

Não se preocupe com usuários imaturos, **você faz um bom trabalho de colaboração** com a comunidade e *se ele não entende* mesmo você explicando como funciona o site, azar o dele, se ele não gosta de como funcionam as coisas por aqui ele é livre pra sair e volte apenas quando entender, *se entender*.

Muitos ficam defendendo coisas como (nem todo mundo faz isto, alguns apenas):

- *Temos que ser bonzinhos*
- *Isso vai espantar os novos usuários*

Para mim o que atrai usuários é a qualidade do conteúdo do site e como funciona a organização aqui. Sim, eu acho que não devemos ser grosseiros ou ríspidos mesmo quando o outro usuário é desagradável, mas sinceramente acho que existem limites, acredito que pessoas que não *querem* entender não valem a pena e dificilmente colaboram com algo para o site, mesmo quando tentamos ser agradáveis e tentamos explicar para que ele não se sinta atacado.

Passei diversas situações semelhantes, sempre consegui contornar seguindo as dicas do *@bfavaretto*, *@Jorgeb.*, *@Gabe*, *@Math*, etc.

Houve uma situação aonde o usuário respondeu uma pergunta minha, o que ele respondeu praticamente já estava na minha pergunta e o que perguntava era outra coisa sobre o assunto (*eu não vou linkar aqui pois pode não ser de bom tom*), admito que fiz um comentário um pouco *humorado demais*, algo como:

> leia a pergunta de novo, não foi isto que perguntei :)

Pronto foi o suficiente para ele começar a bagunça. Foi mais ou menos assim:

- Pedi desculpas pelo comentário tentei explicar a pergunta novamente
- Ele já sentia *a vitima* cheio de *mimimi* e cheio de *eu sou a vitima aqui e portanto você tem que se calar* com ar de superioridade (foi até engraçado)
- Tentei pedir desculpas de novo e disse *vamos por uma pedra em cima disso e começar de novo*.
- Mas ele veio com uns ataques de *mimimi* e não teve jeito.
- No dia seguinte ele deletou a resposta.

Alguns dias depois ele foi bloqueado pois havia deletado algumas respostas próprias dele e/ou por ter recebido negativos em outras respostas, então ele abriu uma questão no meta, no qual ele acusava algum suposto moderador em questões de ética (ainda achando que aqui é fórum).

Alguns usuários que tem pontuação alta para ver respostas deletadas disseram para ele que o bloqueio foi devido a *baixa contribuição* e que ele poderia restaurar uma das respostas deletadas, em especial a que estava na minha pergunta, ele respondeu:

> Esta em especial o autor além de não dar uma especificação inicial, ainda me "esnobou" em outro ponto (aonde me senti desrespeitado), dando origem à discussão, onde exclui por não achar edificante ao site, mas vou fazer esta tentativa.

Eu pedi desculpa ao menos 3 vezes pra ele e ainda sim disse que o *esnobei*, até aonde sei *esnobar* é o ato de se achar superior e quem se acha superior não pede desculpas, resumindo não adianta ser grosseiro com quem é grosseiro, mas as vezes também não adianta gentiliza, melhor ser firme e sério ou não falar mais nada.

### Conclusão

Sei que a historia foi longa, mas pra concluir e resumir, se o usuário mesmo que expliquemos vem aqui achando que somos um tipo fórum, que aqui é bagunça e gosta de se fazer de vitima, então provavelmente (não em todos casos) são pessoas que não sabem conviver em comunidade e que dificilmente vem aqui pra colaborar.

Daniel você esta fazendo um bom trabalho, é prestativo e já faz mais do que o suficiente, se o usuário não entende mesmo você explicando, esqueça ele provavelmente **não** fará diferença para a comunidade.

Este usuário que você citou tem *303 pontos*, ou seja tem participação o suficiente pra entender como funciona a comunidade, se não entendeu até agora é ele quem tem que rever as próprias atitudes.

Conversando com o @IgorContini me lembrei deste link:

- [Seja respeitoso/be nice](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

No momento que o autor comentou:

> se não quiser ajudar nem comenta

Ele deveria ter presumido boa intenção de sua parte, recomendo que sempre envie este link para quem não entende bem a comunidade, para que pessoas assim entendam que o seu comentário não foi um ataque pessoal e sim uma critica construtiva.

Isso é basicamente tudo que você precisa saber, mas vale a pena reforçar 3 pontos:

- **Nunca é permitido agir de forma grosseira ou menosprezar os outros.** Escreva como se estivesse conversando com alguém que você respeita, e que gostaria que te respeitasse também. Se você não tem tempo, ou paciência, para escrever algo construtivo, melhor não escrever nada
- **Seja receptivo**, paciente e sempre presuma boas intenções. Não exija que usuários novos saibam todas as regras do site — eles não vão saber. Então seja paciente enquanto eles estão aprendendo. Se você veio procurar ajuda, facilite o trabalho de quem quer te ajudar. Aqui todos são voluntários, e ninguém vai gostar se você agir como se alguém fosse obrigado a te ajudar.
- **Não seja um idiota.** Entre os comportamentos que não aceitos no site, e devem sempre ser sinalizados, estão:

  1. **Ataques pessoais** O debate deve sempre girar em torno do post, nunca dos autores. Isso inclui termos que atingem a pessoa, mesmo quando aplicados ao post, como "preguiçoso" ou "ignorante".
     Qualquer tipo de linguagem preconceituosa. Não são toleradas palavras ou expressões que possam ofender ou alienar indivíduos ou grupos, com base em raça, gênero, orientação sexual, religião, etc. Esses são apenas alguns exemplos; na dúvida, melhor não dizer nada.
  2. **Linguagem imprópria.** Evite usar termos vulgares ou de teor sexual. Esse não é um site de namoro.
  3. **Assédio e intimidação.** Todas as interação hostis devem ser sinalizadas. Caso a pessoa não pare com os ataques, nos avise e nós tomaremos as medidas necessárias. Se você ver algo que necessite de atenção da equipe do site, entre em contato. O link está no rodapé do site.

Comment: Eu não sei o que é esnobar lol

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu estava pensando que você iria vir comentar algo e veio mesmo kkkk !!

Comment: Sou assim tão previsível? ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Para quem frequenta o pt.se talvez sim :)

Comment: Ótima resposta, vejo que novatos reclamam e as vezes deixam o site por terem que ler uma RF de regras(cap1 => tour).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Zoeira ou brincadeiras a parte aqui pode em qualquer lugar? As vezes é ótimo descontrais um pouco.

Comment: @rray Zoeira ou brincadeiras a parte aqui pode em qualquer lugar? As vezes é ótimo descontrais um pouco.

Comment: @IgorContini No site pode sim ter senso de humor, mas sem faltar com respeito, no caso do usuário que citei ele se doeu pois provavelmente não esta acostumado nem com brincadeiras simples e provavelmente queria mostrar alguma seriedade, levando tudo aos extremos. No caso aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice fala *Seja receptivo, paciente e sempre presuma boas intenções.*, ou seja ele não presumiu a boa ação :p

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento realmente ele não presumiu mesmo rs. Estou pensando formular uma pergunta e pergunta no meta sobre isso. Queria saber a opinião de outros pessoas influentes e dos moderadores!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a minha pergunta vai ser direcionada a brincadeiras e zoeiras pois tem gente que já esta acostumado a zoar e brincar mas tem outras que não estão acostumadas podendo acarreta ofendimento se a pessoa leva para a parte pessoal. Geralmente acontece muitas brigas e discussões por causa disso!

Comment: @IgorContini Eu nem tinha consciência deste problema, se o problema existe então faça, será uma ótima pergunta e com certeza ajudará muitos, será um bom link para indicar aos novatos :D